# java access modifier knocking out each other?

Tags: android, android-adapter, access-modifiers, android-viewholder

Currently i am developing an android project using Android Studio 3 using SDK 19. My personal target was, to produce code with almost no warnings to improve my code quality.

When setting up a `RecyclerViewAdapter` for my `RecyclerView` with a `ViewHolder` as inner class I came through this odd behavior of Android Studio that it marks the access of my `ViewHolder` to be able to be private. However when I do this, I get an error already in the declaration of my `RecyclerView.Adapter` class. Any Idea what i'm doing wrong in particular?

This is the skeleton structure of my `ErrorCompactAdapter`:

```
public class ErrorCompactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ErrorCompactAdapter.ErrorCompactViewHolder> {

    //fields and attributes
    //cotr
    //onCreateViewHolder
    //onBindViewHolder
    //getItemCount

    protected class ErrorCompactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        //outlets
        //cotr

    }
}
```

The warning explicitly says, that the access of `ErrorCompactViewHolder` can be private. If I change this  I get an Error message saying that `ErrorCompactAdapter.ErrorCompactViewHolder has a private access in ErrorCompactAdapter`. This is kinda confusing, can you imagine? Any idea, if I digged my self a trap hole somewhere? Thanks in forward.

Comment: Are you sure that it says that it can be **private**, not **package-private**?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko that is indeed a point i didn't look at. It says package-private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studio suggest you to change the access modifier of `ErrorCompactViewHolder` to **package-private**, not to **private**, which is a big difference.
Package-private is a default access modifier in Java, which means that the class will be available in scope of it's package.

To give the class default (package-private) access modifier, you need to remove the access modifier at all.

Answer (score 0):

Should it be private static field?

Comment: it's supposed to be not static.